# After importing the DoWhy package, Python is unable to perform arithmetic operations

Tags: causal-inference, dowhy

I use jupyter notebook and the kernek is an enviroment created by anaconda
python version is 3.9
dowhy version is 0.8
Before I import dowhy, Python can calculate 3-2.
But after, it cant.
There is no errer massage. Programme runs continuously. I even cant interrupt it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY8uP.png)

I run this code in promt, it can be calculated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSzvF.png)